# Connection reset error when trying to connect to Salesforce from WSO2 ESB 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, salesforce, esb, connection-reset

I'm getting a connection reset error when trying to create a case or an event in the salesforce from WSO2 ESB proxy services. This is happening very frequently.

Anyone having an idea on how to prevent these exceptions?

I have already checked trust.salesforce.com and found no problems in my instance and also verified there are no reported issues around that time.
I have tried same thing in external API tool 'workbench' and there are no issues.

Here's the logs for this exception

````
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:659)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaGet(HTTPSender.java:104)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:63)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:293)
at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:194)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:125)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:69)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:134)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:210)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.processThoughEngine(JMSMessageReceiver.java:214)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.onMessage(JMSMessageReceiver.java:124)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.handleMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:634)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:515)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)```
````